# OpenCL read_imagef weird behaviour

Tags: image, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

I have an image with CL_FLOAT format and stores all RGBA channels. Now every 4th pixel of image has integers stored there, I store them clasically as:

```
image[i * 4 + 3].x = *(float*)(&someInt);
image[i * 4 + 3].y = *(float*)(&someInt2);
etc.
```

And as I need these to be integers (and not floats), the rest of the pixels have to store floats, so I don't have much options here.

When I read image back from OpenCL I get the values correctly, the problem arises in OpenCL kernel:

Whenever I read image like this (sampler is set just to nearest filtering):

```
float4 fourthPixel = read_imagef(img, sampler, coords);
```

And I try to convert it to integer as

```
int id = as_int(fourthPixel.x);
```

I don't read correct number (it always returns 0, unless number is quite high in integer form).

I got few points so far - if I store number like 1505353234 it WORKS, giving me back 6539629947781120.000000 - which is correct. If I store smaller numbers, it seems that read_imagef just clamps then down to 0.

So it's quite obvious, that ALL denormalized numbers are clamped down to zero. So, is there any good way to actually force read_imagef to not clamp down denormalized numbers to zero, without adding further instruction (ye i could add 0x7f000000 or such - but I need performance in the code, so this solution is unacceptable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently reading image through read_imagei works fine. I also looked to specs and found out that your device *can* clamp denormalized floats to zero.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?